# react native - add diffrent icons to items and also make them pressable

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, svg

I work with the 'react-native-super-grid' library and I trying to figure out how to do the following 2 situations:

1. Displays a different icon for each item in the grid
   for example : the PinIcon will be for the 'qq' and the CatIcon will be for the 'ww'.
2. How to make the items clickable with 'pressable' or 'TouchableOpacity'

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';
import PinIcon from '../src/assets/PinIcon.svg';
import CatIcon from '../src/assets/CatIcon.svg';

  const HomeComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { name: 'qq', code: 'white' },
    { name: 'ww', code: 'white' },
    { name: `ee`, code: 'white' },
    { name: 'rr', code: 'white' },
    { name: 'tt', code: 'white' },
    { name: 'yy', code: 'white' },
    { name: 'uu', code: 'white' },
  ]);

  return (
    <FlatGrid
      itemDimension={130}
      data={items}
      style={styles.gridView}
      spacing={10}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: item.code }]}>
          <PinIcon />
          <CatIcon />
          <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemCode}>{item.code}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the icon to items as icon props initially and to make the icon touchable, wrap icon with  `Pressable` or `TouchableOpacity` and pass the function in `onPress` props like below

```
...
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { name: 'qq', code: 'white', icon: <PinIcon/> },
    { name: 'ww', code: 'white', icon: <CatIcon/> },
    { name: `ee`, code: 'white', icon: <DogIcon/> },
    ...
  ]);
...
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={[styles.itemContainer, { backgroundColor: item.code }]}>
      <Pressable onPress={()=>onPressFunctionHere()}>
      {item.icon}
      </Pressable>
      <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.itemCode}>{item.code}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
```

Comment: i need not only 2 icons.. i need icon to every item so how can i achieve that ? 
i mean i need also 'DogIcon' to 'ee' and to all the items also..

Comment: then you need to make an icon array corresponding to index of items or map the items and pass the icon to items.

Comment: can u show me please how to do it ?  show me the code

Comment: Try updated code